# Python - LightGBM with GridSearchCV, is running forever

Tags: python, cross-validation, xgboost, grid-search, lightgbm

Recently, I am doing multiple experiments to compare Python XgBoost and LightGBM. It seems that this LightGBM is a new algorithm that people say it works better than XGBoost in both speed and accuracy.

This is [LightGBM GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM).
This is [LightGBM python API documents](http://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/lightgbm.html#), here you will find python functions you can call. It can be directly called from LightGBM model and also can be called by LightGBM scikit-learn.

This is the [XGBoost Python API](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) I use. As you can see, it has very similar data structure as LightGBM python API above.

Here are what I tried:

1. If you use `train()` method in both XGBoost and LightGBM, yes lightGBM works faster and has higher accuracy. But this method, doesn't have cross validation.
2. If you try `cv()` method in both algorithms, it is for cross validation. However, I didn't find a way to use it return a set of optimum parameters.
3. if you try scikit-learn `GridSearchCV()` with LGBMClassifier and XGBClassifer. It works for XGBClassifer, but for LGBClassifier, it is running forever.

Here are my code examples when using `GridSearchCV()` with both classifiers:

**XGBClassifier with GridSearchCV**

```
param_set = {
 'n_estimators':[50, 100, 500, 1000]
}
gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator = XGBClassifier( learning_rate =0.1, 
n_estimators=100, max_depth=5,
min_child_weight=1, gamma=0, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=0.8, 
nthread=7,
objective= 'binary:logistic', scale_pos_weight=1, seed=410), 
param_grid = param_set, scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=7,iid=False, cv=10)

xgb_model2 = gsearch.fit(features_train, label_train)
xgb_model2.grid_scores_, xgb_model2.best_params_, xgb_model2.best_score_
```

This works very well for XGBoost, and only tool a few seconds.

**LightGBM with GridSearchCV**

```
param_set = {
 'n_estimators':[20, 50]
}

gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator = LGBMClassifier( boosting_type='gbdt', num_leaves=30, max_depth=5, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=50, max_bin=225, 
 subsample_for_bin=0.8, objective=None, min_split_gain=0, 
 min_child_weight=5, 
 min_child_samples=10, subsample=1, subsample_freq=1, 
colsample_bytree=1, 
reg_alpha=1, reg_lambda=0, seed=410, nthread=7, silent=True), 
param_grid = param_set, scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=7,iid=False, cv=10)

lgb_model2 = gsearch.fit(features_train, label_train)
lgb_model2.grid_scores_, lgb_model2.best_params_, lgb_model2.best_score_
```

However, by using this method for LightGBM, it has been running the whole morning today still nothing generated.

I am using the same dataset, a dataset contains 30000 records.

**I have 2 questions:**

1. If we just use `cv()` method, is there anyway to tune optimum set of parameters?
2. Do you know why `GridSearchCV()` does not work well with LightGBM? I'm wondering whether this only happens on me all it happened on others to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `n_jobs = 1` and see if it works.

In general, if you use `n_jobs = -1` or `n_jobs > 1` then you should protect your script by using `if __name__=='__main__':` :

**Simple Example:**

```
import ...

if __name__=='__main__':

    data= pd.read_csv('Prior Decompo2.csv', header=None)
    X, y = data.iloc[0:, 0:26].values, data.iloc[0:,26].values
    param_grid = {'C' : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10], 'kernel': ('rbf', 'linear')}
    classifier = SVC()
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, verbose=42)
    grid_search.fit(X,y)
```

Finally, can you try to run your code using  `n_jobs = -1` and including `if __name__=='__main__':` as I explained and see if it works?

Comment: @CherryWu  I will test it on my laptop and let you know if I can reproduce the problem when n_jobs = -1

Answer (score 0):

The original problem is due to `lightgbm` and `GridSearchCV` starting too many threads (i.e. more than available on the machine). If the product (or a sum? it depends on how `GridSearchCV` is implemented) of those is still within machine capabilities, then it will run. It there are too many threads they clash and `lightgbm` stops execution for some unclear to me - but known to developers - reason.