# GridSearchCV with lightgbm requires fit() method not used?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, lightgbm

I am trying to carry out a `GridSearchCV` using `sklearn` on an LightGBM estimator but am running into problems when building the search.

My code to build looks as such:

```
d_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)
params = {}
params['learning_rate'] = 0.003
params['boosting_type'] = 'gbdt'
params['objective'] = 'binary'
params['metric'] = 'binary_logloss'
params['sub_feature'] = 0.5
params['num_leaves'] = 10
params['min_data'] = 50
params['max_depth'] = 10

clf = lgb.train(params, d_train, 100)

param_grid = {
    'num_leaves': [10, 31, 127],
    'boosting_type': ['gbdt', 'rf'],
    'learning rate': [0.1, 0.001, 0.003]
    }


gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid)
lgb_model = gsearch.fit(X=train, y=y)
```

However I am running into the following error:

```
TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, 
          <lightgbm.basic.Booster object at 0x0000014C55CA2880> was passed
```

LightGBM however is trained using the `train()` method and not `fit()` therefore is this grid search not useable?

Thanks

Comment: Where does lgb come from?

Have you checked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045938/python-lightgbm-with-gridsearchcv-is-running-forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lgb` object you are using does not support the `scikit-learn` API. This is why you cannot use it in such way.

However, the `lightgbm` package offers classes that are compliant with the `scikit-learn` API. Depending on which supervised learning task you are trying to accomplish, classification or regression, use either [`LGBMClassifier`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier)  or [`LGBMRegressor`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#lightgbm.LGBMRegressor). An example for a classification task:

```
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


clf = LGBMClassifier()
param_grid = {
    'num_leaves': [10, 31, 127],
    'boosting_type': ['gbdt', 'rf'],
    'learning rate': [0.1, 0.001, 0.003]
}

gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid)
gsearch.fit(X_train, y_train)
```